# Elevator capacity

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have this problem for school. I know I am almost right but it seems I have a problem somewhere in the code. The question is that I have 2 values which are entered by the user.The first (n) is the number of people that want to go into an elevator and the second (p) is the amount of people the elevator can take. The question is how many trips will the elevator make in order to take all the people to selected floor.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Elevator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int p = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            int elevatorTrips = 0;
            elevatorTrips = n / p;

            if (elevatorTrips % 10 != 0)
            {
                elevatorTrips += 1;
                Console.WriteLine(elevatorTrips);
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine(elevatorTrips);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the exact problem you have when you run the code? Does it only happen when you have a fraction after the division?

Comment: Off-Topic. Did you debug your code to see how many times it takes?

Comment: loop for `n-p` until it's `<= 0` or shorten it with division `n/p`, if there is any remainder add `1`

Comment: The question to ask yourself is: where did that 10 come from?  Is there some better value to put there?  Try testing your work with a lot of different     inputs for `n` and `p`, and see if they all get good results.

Comment: Why not divide and get the `double` answer then round it up ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do it. Use [Math.Ceiling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/zx4t0t48(v=vs.110).aspx).

From MSDN:

> Returns the smallest integral value that is greater than or equal to the specified double-precision floating-point number.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Elevator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int p = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            var elevatorTrips = Math.Ceiling((double)n / p);

            Console.WriteLine(elevatorTrips);
        }
    }
}
```

DotNet-Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/srLTVZ

Answer (score 0):

Divide `TotalNumberOfPeople` over `ElevatorCapacity` and get the answer as a `double`, Then round it up to the first bigger `int` so you could know if you have decimals or not. This way, IF you have a decimal it will be converted to 1 (and added to the final result)

P.S: You could round up by adding `0.5` to whatever the `double` answer is, then simply assign it to another int variable and you will get your final solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see; suppose we have `13` people in a queue and lift's capacity is `3`, so the answer is `5`:

```
  4 turns with 3 peoples
  1 turn  with 1 people
```

Can you see the pattern? `peoples / capacity` trips with lift *full loaded*, and, probably, an additional trip with lift *partially loaded*. And the solution is quite simple

```
  int capacity = 3;
  int peoples = 13; 

  int trips = peoples / capacity + (peoples % capacity != 0 ? 1 : 0);
```

In your current implementation it's

```
  if (elevatorTrips % 10 != 0)
```

that's *wrong*: what *magic number* `10` stands for?